# Undefined process.env variable with dotenv and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, environment-variables

I have a problem with the dotenv package.

My application folder:

```
 |_app_folder
      |_app.js
      |_password.env
      |_package.json
```

I've of course install dotenv, but when i tried to log a process.env variables, the result is always undefined, please can you help me ?

**password.env** :

```
//password.env 
CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxx
```

**app.js** :

```
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Twig = require("twig");

//Require dotenv
require('dotenv').config();

// Setting the Twig options
app.set("twig options", {
    allow_async: true, 
    strict_variables: false
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  //Trying to log it
  console.log(process.env.CLIENT_ID);
  //
  res.render('index.twig', {
    date : new Date().toString()
  });
});

app.get('/instagram',function(req,res){
  // Building the URL
  let url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=';
  // Redirect to instagram for oauth 
  res.redirect(url);
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Running');
})
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default the dotenv package does only load a file named `.env` if you want to load another file you need to specify the path

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "path/to/file" })
```

Resources:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Thanks you i didn't know that, i replace the require with this one : require("dotenv").config(path.join(__dirname,'password.env'));
but it still don't work

Comment: Try to log the path you are creating and check if it is correct

Comment: i've did and it's the good one : /home/thomas/instagram-oauth-login/password.env

Comment: No problem, I messed that up! Sorry

Comment: As a complement I had a weird case where the **.env** file is not loaded either, and I had to add 
**require("dotenv").config({path:".env"})**

Answer (score 5):

When using **import** instead of **require**. -

You can use -r (require) to preload dotenv. You do not need to require and load dotenv in your application code.

```
 $ node -r dotenv/config app.js
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having somewhat the same problem for a while turns out you just have to put the `.env` file in the root of the directory (top-most level).

I know this post is old but I just want to make sure no one struggles with such a simple task again.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I put the .env file in the root folder, still console.log(process.env.myKey) is undefined. The fix worked for me is I put the path to the env file in the require config itself like below. (It's in the root of the file - so "./.env)

```
require("dotenv").config({path:"./.env"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another important note:

Place your .env file in the root folder, not in /src